# I was wondering if someone could help me re-format my code to fix the loop I made

Tags: processing

I was wondering what mistake I made in the line that is formatted like this "''" because I was wondering why my code wouldn't move back to the right to bounce back and forth between walls. I put the code that I need help in with single quotations. This is my frist time on stack, so any tips would be appreciated.

```
PImage invader, invader2, invader3, invader4, invader5, space, tank;
int tankX = 400;
PImage [] picArray = new PImage [7];
int invaderState = 2;
int timer = 0;
int lap = 0;
int [] alienXPos = {100, 180, 260, 340, 420, 500, 580, 660, 740, 820};
//had to add a few zeros on alienYPos otherwise the loop would bug out and wouldn't work
int[] alienYPos  =  {40, 140, 240, 340, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};
boolean moveLeft, moveRight;
int paddleSpeed = 3;
int gameState = 1;
String message1 = "Welcome to space invaders!";
String message2 = "Click space to start!";
boolean movingLeft, movingRight;

void setup() {
  size(1000, 1000);
  invader = loadImage("invader.jpg");
  invader.resize(70, 50);
  invader2 = loadImage("invader2.png");
  invader2.resize(70, 50);
  space = loadImage("space.png");
  space.resize(1000, 1000);
  tank = loadImage("tank.png");
  tank.resize(150, 100);
}

void draw() {

  background(space);

  timer = millis();

  if (timer-lap>800) {
    lap = timer;

   ' **for (int m=0; m <10; m++) {

      if (movingRight == false) {
        alienXPos[m] += 40;
      } else {
        alienXPos[m] -= 40;
      }
      if (alienXPos [m] > 900 && movingRight == false) {
        movingRight = true;
        for (int l=0; l<10; l++) {
          alienYPos[l] += 75;
                       println("movingleft : " + movingLeft);
                       println("Moving right : " + movingRight);
        }
       // if(movingLeft == false){
        // alienXPos[m] -= 55;
        //}
         //else{
          // alienXPos [m] += 40;
         //}

         
 if (movingLeft == false) {
        //alienXPos[m] -=55;
      } /*else {
        alienXPos[m] ;
      }*/
        if (alienXPos[m] < 100 && movingLeft == true) {
          movingLeft = false;
          movingRight = true;
         /*for (int l=0; l<10; l++) {
          alienYPos[l] += 75;
        }** '
             println("movingLeft : " + movingLeft);
*/
        }
      }
    }
    /* if (alienXPos[m] > 0 && movingLeft == true) {
     alienXPos[m] -= 55;
     
     }*/





    if (invaderState == 1) {

      invaderState = 2;
    } else {

      invaderState = 1;
    }
  }

  if (tankX > width) {
    tankX = 0;
  }
  if (tankX < 0) {
    tankX = 1000;
  }
  if (gameState == 1) {
    drawGameState1();
  } else if (gameState == 2) {
    drawGameState2();
  }
}



void drawGameState1() {
  background(#222222);
  fill(#000000);
  textSize(36);
  fill(130, 130, 130);
  text(message1, 300, 450);
  textSize(20);
  text(message2, 430, 600);
}
void drawGameState2() {
  background(space);
  drawSpaceInvader1();
  drawTank();
  drawTankMovement();
}


void drawSpaceInvader1() {
  for (int i=0; i< 10; i++) {
    if (invaderState == 1) {
      image(invader, alienXPos[i], alienYPos[0]);
      image(invader, alienXPos[i], alienYPos[1]);
      image(invader, alienXPos[i], alienYPos[2]);
      image(invader, alienXPos[i], alienYPos[3]);
    } else if (invaderState == 2) {

      image(invader2, alienXPos[i], alienYPos[0]);
      image(invader2, alienXPos[i], alienYPos[1]);
      image(invader2, alienXPos[i], alienYPos[2]);
      image(invader2, alienXPos[i], alienYPos[3]);
    }
  }
}

void drawTank() {
  image(tank, tankX, 700);
}
void drawTankMovement() {
  if (moveLeft) {
    tankX -= 25;
  }
  if (moveRight) {
    tankX += 25;
  }
}
void keyPressed() {
  if (gameState == 1) {
    if (keyCode == 32) {
      gameState = 2;
    }
  }
  if (gameState == 2) {
    if (keyCode == LEFT) {
      moveLeft = true;
    }
    if (keyCode == RIGHT) {

      moveRight = true;
    }
  }
}
void keyReleased() {
  if (keyCode == LEFT) { // Left Key
    moveLeft = false;
  }

  if (keyCode == RIGHT) { // Right Key
    moveRight = false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A few things:

- Next time, please try and provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), you were almost there, but you forgot to attach the image files that you use to draw your game out. Running this code gave me errors saying I was missing a few files. I took the liberty of importing some nonsense image and reusing that as your missing assets.
- Also missing from your answer is a more implicit title. I think you misunderstood the term "reformatting" code, as that generally refers to the [formatting of code](http://c2.com/ppr/formatting.html). To make your answer likely to be found by others with the same problem, please consider changing the title to what your question is actually about: You can't figure out why your code doesn't reverse the movement of your row of space invaders. Next time, please read [this guide](https://medium.com/@gordon_zhu/how-to-be-great-at-asking-questions-e37be04d0603) on how to write a proper question.

### Now to answer your question:

I ran your code and noticed that `movingLeft` was false whilst `movingRight` was true. Yet your invaders seem to be running towards the left side of the screen. One of your mistakes was probably getting confused by these variables.

In your code you do

```
if (movingRight == false) {
  alienXPos[m] += 40;
} else {
  alienXPos[m] -= 40;
}
```

Which effectively does the opposite of what you want. In coordinates are oriented like this, assuming we have a 800x400 canvas:
[image: sketch of axis coords on 800x400 canvas]

So if you want your invaders to move right, you should be adding to the coordinates when the bool is true, not when it's false. Your logic which flips the invaders direction should be sound:

```
if (alienXPos[m] < 100 && movingLeft == true) {
   movingLeft = false;
   movingRight = true;
}
```

But since in your program due to the above logic error movingLeft is never true, this statement will never run.

One suggestion is that in the simple case of space invaders you don't really need to keep track of two seperate moving variables for each direction, after all, invaders either:

- Move to the right

or

- Move to the left

Thus you could ditch having two variables and just check, for example, `movingRight`. If that is true, the invaders should be moving to the right, and if it's false, they should be moving to the left.

Comment: thank you so much in helping me